# C# Pasar una lista de un Form a otro

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Tengo en el formulario **FormConsultarAlumnos** una lista y la quiero pasar a el formulario **FormAgregarCalificacion**. Esta la envie por el constructor al formulario receptor sin embargo no se porque la cuando intento imprimir la lista en un DGV o demás cosas no me lo permite (al parecer los objetos que guarde ahí no están). Podrían ayudarme... Gracias

**FormConsultarAlumnos**

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    public partial class FormConsultarAlumnos : Form
    {

        public static List<EstudianteMatriculado> ListaEstudiante = new List<EstudianteMatriculado>();
        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();

        public FormConsultarAlumnos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");

            EstudianteMatriculado alumno1 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Alejandra", "Bejarano Montero", 1759869, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno2 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Giancarlo", "Mendoza Muñoz", 1759620, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno3 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Camilo", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759589, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno4 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Mia", "Thermopolis", 1759756, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno5 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Laura", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759770, 50, 0);

            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno1);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno2);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno3);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno4);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno5);

            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno1.NombreAlumno, alumno1.ApellidoAlumno, alumno1.Codigo, alumno1.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno2.NombreAlumno, alumno2.ApellidoAlumno, alumno2.Codigo, alumno2.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno3.NombreAlumno, alumno3.ApellidoAlumno, alumno3.Codigo, alumno3.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno4.NombreAlumno, alumno4.ApellidoAlumno, alumno4.Codigo, alumno4.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno5.NombreAlumno, alumno5.ApellidoAlumno, alumno5.Codigo, alumno5.Grupo);

            dgvEstudiantes.DataSource = directorio;

        }

        FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion(ListaEstudiante);
```

**FormAgregarCalificacion**

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    public partial class FormAgregarCalificacion : Form
    {
        //public List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaAlumno = new List<EstudianteMatriculado>();
        public EstudianteMatriculado listaAlumno;
        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();

        public FormAgregarCalificacion(List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaEstudiante)
        {

            listaAlumno = listaEstudiante;


        }



        public FormAgregarCalificacion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Calificación");




            dgvCalificacion.DataSource = listaAlumno;
            dgvCalificacion.DataSource = directorio;
        }
```

La lista nueva en el form receptor (FormAgregarCalificacion) es de tipo **EstudianteMAtriculado** ya que en esta clase cree un objeto alumno.

Comment: Porque `FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion(ListaEstudiante);` esta fuera del contructor de la clase `FormConsultarAlumnos `?

Comment: Entiendo...Aun sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Era una pregunta, no obstante si te ayudó dejalo saber.

Comment: Aun no me imprime nada

Comment: Aca veo otro inconveniente `listaAlumno = listaEstudiante;` Aqui estas diciendo que la variable `listaEstudiante` es una lista de elementos de tipo `EstudianteMatriculado` que se recibe a traves del constructor de la clase, sin embargo lo que veo es que estas asignando una lista de elementos de tipo `EstudianteMatriculado` a una variable de tipo `EstudianteMatriculado`...En el formulario `FormAgregarCalificacion` intenta cambiar `public EstudianteMatriculado listaAlumno;` por `public List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaAlumno;`

Comment: Ya lo había hecho ante pero tampoco funciono

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Pasar una lista entre formularios C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319786/pasar-una-lista-entre-formularios-c)

Comment: Esta pregunta, ha sido formulada 3 veces contando esta misma y estas dos :  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/319786/69447 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/319828/69447

Answer (score 0):

Para afirmar conocimientos, cuando un constructor de vista se debe cargar no te olvides de inicializar los componentes = InitializeComponent(); y estas trabajando con un constructor "Sobre Cargado". lo cual la logica esta puesta en el constructor equivocado.