# Pasar una lista entre formularios C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Tengo en el formulario FormConsultarAlumnos una lista y la quiero pasar a el formulario FormAgregarCalificacion. Esta la envie por el constructor al formulario receptor sin embargo no se porque la cuando intento imprimir la lista en un DGV o demás cosas no me lo permite (al parecer los objetos que guarde ahí no están). Podrían ayudarme... Gracias

**FormAgregarCalificacion**

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    public partial class FormAgregarCalificacion : Form
    {
        public List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaAlumno;

        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();

        public FormAgregarCalificacion(List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaEstudiante)
        {

            listaAlumno = listaEstudiante;

        }



        public FormAgregarCalificacion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Calificación");



            dgvCalificacion.DataSource = directorio;


        }
```

**FormConsultarAlumnos**

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    public partial class FormConsultarAlumnos : Form
    {

        public static List<EstudianteMatriculado> ListaEstudiante = new List<EstudianteMatriculado>();
        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();

        public FormConsultarAlumnos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();




            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");

            EstudianteMatriculado alumno1 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Alejandra", "Bejarano Montero", 1759869, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno2 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Giancarlo", "Mendoza Muñoz", 1759620, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno3 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Camilo", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759589, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno4 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Mia", "Thermopolis", 1759756, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno5 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Laura", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759770, 50, 0);

            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno1);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno2);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno3);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno4);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno5);

            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno1.NombreAlumno, alumno1.ApellidoAlumno, alumno1.Codigo, alumno1.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno2.NombreAlumno, alumno2.ApellidoAlumno, alumno2.Codigo, alumno2.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno3.NombreAlumno, alumno3.ApellidoAlumno, alumno3.Codigo, alumno3.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno4.NombreAlumno, alumno4.ApellidoAlumno, alumno4.Codigo, alumno4.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno5.NombreAlumno, alumno5.ApellidoAlumno, alumno5.Codigo, alumno5.Grupo);

            dgvEstudiantes.DataSource = directorio;

            FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion(ListaEstudiante);
        }
```

La lista nueva en el form receptor (FormAgregarCalificacion) es de tipo EstudianteMAtriculado ya que en esta clase cree un objeto alumno.

Comment: Estas usando mvc o asp.net con webforms? Si es webforms trata de guardar la información en variables de Session o cache.

Comment: Esta publicación debería ser marcada como duplicada, mirar esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/319828/69447

Answer (score 1):

Aclarando, son Windows Forms.

No la pases parámetros al constructor, a menos que modifique realmente como se construye el objeto. En tu caso más que una variable pública, debió ser una propiedad Get/Set.

Deja solo un constructor predeterminado sin parámetros.

Luego de crear FormAgregarCalificacion

```
FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion();
FormAgregarCalificacion.listaAlumno = ListaEstudiante;
```

Esta declaración estática, te dará problemas siempre que pases la referencia del miembro estático.

```
public static List<EstudianteMatriculado> ListaEstudiante
```

Además: dgvCalificacion.DataSource = directorio;  //directorio está vacío! //solo tiene definiciones de columnas, en algún momento debes llenarlo con los datos en tu lista

**Consejo: usa los mecanismos de depuración de VS, breakpoint, inspect, etc, para que veas si tus objetos tienen datos**