# Pasar una lista de un formulario a otro en C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Tengo en el formulario FormConsultarAlumnos una lista y la quiero pasar a el formulario FormAgregarCalificacion. Esta la envie por el constructor al formulario receptor sin embargo no se porque la cuando intento imprimir la lista en un DGV o demás cosas no me lo permite (al parecer los objetos que guarde ahí no están). Podrían ayudarme... Gracias

FormAgregarCalificacion

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    public partial class FormAgregarCalificacion : Form
    {
        public static List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaAlumno;

        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();

        public FormAgregarCalificacion(List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaEstudiante)
        {



            listaAlumno = listaEstudiante; 





        }



        public FormAgregarCalificacion()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Calificación");


            dgvCalificacion.DataSource = listaAlumno;

            dgvCalificacion.DataSource = directorio;


        }
```

```
**FormConsultarAlumnos**

namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    public partial class FormConsultarAlumnos : Form
    {

        public static List<EstudianteMatriculado> ListaEstudiante = new List<EstudianteMatriculado>();
        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();

        public FormConsultarAlumnos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");

            EstudianteMatriculado alumno1 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Alejandra", "Bejarano Montero", 1759869, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno2 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Giancarlo", "Mendoza Muñoz", 1759620, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno3 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Camilo", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759589, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno4 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Mia", "Thermopolis", 1759756, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno5 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Laura", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759770, 50, 0);

            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno1);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno2);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno3);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno4);
            ListaEstudiante.Add(alumno5);

            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno1.NombreAlumno, alumno1.ApellidoAlumno, alumno1.Codigo, alumno1.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno2.NombreAlumno, alumno2.ApellidoAlumno, alumno2.Codigo, alumno2.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno3.NombreAlumno, alumno3.ApellidoAlumno, alumno3.Codigo, alumno3.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno4.NombreAlumno, alumno4.ApellidoAlumno, alumno4.Codigo, alumno4.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno5.NombreAlumno, alumno5.ApellidoAlumno, alumno5.Codigo, alumno5.Grupo);

            dgvEstudiantes.DataSource = directorio;

            FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion(ListaEstudiante);
        }
```

La lista nueva ubicada en el Form **FormAgregarCalificacion** es de tipo **EstudianteMatriculado** ya que fue ahi donde cree la lista y agregue los objetos de este tipo.

No se porque no aparece en el dgv o simplemente dice que no hay elementos cuando la intento recorrer. Tambien ya le hice el debug y la lista pasa con los cinco objetos que están en ella. Por favor necesito de su ayuda.

Comment: Esta publicación debería ser marcada como duplicada, mirar esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/319786/69447

Answer (score 1):

En el constructor donde pasas la lista no estas inicializando los componentes del formulario ni asignado la lista al objecto `dgvCalificacion`.

Cambia :

```
public FormAgregarCalificacion(List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaEstudiante)
{
    listaAlumno = listaEstudiante; 
}
```

Por:

```
public FormAgregarCalificacion(List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaEstudiante)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
    directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
    directorio.Columns.Add("Codigo");
    directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");
    directorio.Columns.Add("Calificación");

    dgvCalificacion.DataSource = listaEstudiante;
    dgvCalificacion.DataSource = directorio;
}
```

Notaras como ahora el constructor que acepta la lista ejecuta el metodo `InitializeComponent()` y tambien asigna la lista al `DataSource` del objeto `dgvCalificacion`.

Recuerda que para inicializar el formulario con data, tienes que utilizar el constructor que acepta el parametro.